# How to revoke myself rights to write files outside current directory?

Tags: linux, shell, file-permissions

I want to make sure commands that I run from my shell cannot damage my files above starting directory. For example, this command should fail: `cd ~/ && rm -rf *`. Supporting links, mount points would be nice but optional.

Comment: It's time to think about having a good backup strategy…

Comment: What does `cd ~/ && rm -rf *` have to do with "files above starting directory"?